# If I have a function that recurses on fibonacci numbers, can I determine how many times it recurses?

Tags: computational-mathematics

Lets say I have the following function:

```
function fib(n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2); 
}
```

For $n = 5$, it calls itself $14$ times. 
For $n = 4$, it calls itself $8$ times.

Is there a formula to figure out how many times it will recurse for any $n$?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738923/number-of-calls-for-nth-fibonacci-number

Comment: The words should be  recur and recurs.